# Сбой при доступе к базе данных (Table does not exist)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

Столкнулся с проблемой работы с базами данных с помощью `php`. В коде вроде все правильно. Проверял 5 раз.

Вызов страницы с формой выдает ошибку о том, что не может найти таблицу, хотя она существует. Если использовать другие базы данных (не test) - выдает ошибку о том, что не может подключиться к базе.
[image: Скрин]

[image: Скрин phpmyadmin]

Файл login.php

```
<?php
  $db_hostname = 'localhost';
  $db_database = 'test';
  $db_username = 'root';
  $db_password = '';
?>
```

Файл sqltest.php

```
<?php
  require_once 'login.php';
  $db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);

  if (!$db_server) die ("Невозможно подключиться к MYSQL: " . mysql_error());   

  mysql_select_db ($db_database, $db_server)
    or die("Невозможно выбрать БД: " . mysql_error());

  if (isset ($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['isbn']))
  {
    $isbn = get_post('isbn');
    $query = "DELETE FROM classics WHERE isbn = '$isbn'";

    if (!mysql_query($query, $db_server))
        echo "Сбой при удалении данных: $query<br>" . 
        mysql_error() . "<br><br>";
  }

  if (isset ($_POST['author']) &&
      isset ($_POST['title']) &&
      isset ($_POST['category']) &&
      isset ($_POST['year']) &&
      isset ($_POST['isbn']))
  {
      $author = get_post('author');
      $title = get_post('title');
      $category = get_post('category');
      $year = get_post('year');
      $isbn = get_post('isbn');

      $query = "INSERT INTO classics VALUES" .
      "('$author', '$title', '$category', '$year', '$isbn')";

      if (!mysql_query($query, $db_server))
        echo "Сбой при вставке данных: $query<br>" .
        mysql_error() . "<br><br>";
  }

  echo <<<_END
   <form action = "sqltest.php" method = "post"><pre>
    Author <input type = "text" name = "author">
    Title <input type = "text" name = "title">
    Category <input type = "text" name = "category">
    Year <input type = "text" name = "year">
    ISBN <input type = "text" name = "isbn">
    <input type = "submit" value = "ADD RECORD">
  </pre></form>
_END;

  $query = "SELECT * FROM classics";
  $result = mysql_query($query);

  if(!$result) die ("Сбой при доступе к БД: " . mysql_error());
  $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

  for($j = 0; $j < $rows; ++$j)
  {
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    echo <<<_END
  <pre>
  Author   $row[0]
  Title    $row[1]
  Category $row[2]
  Year     $row[3]
  ISBN     $row[4]
  </pre>
  <form action = "sqltest.php" method = "post">
  <input type = "hidden" name = "delete" value = "yes">
  <input type = "hidden" name = "isbn" value = "$row[4]">
  <input type = "submit" value = "DELETE RECORD"></form>
_END;
  }

  mysql_close($db_server);

  function get_post($var)
  {
    return mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
  }
?>
```

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться

Comment: у тебя в инсерте VALUES на скриншоте пустые. `mysql_real_escape_string` ошибки не дает?

Comment: добавь в начало файла php код - `error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);`

Comment: Сбой при доступе к БД появляется еще до отправки формы. И формы вообще должно быть две, а так же вывод всех таблиц моей базы.

Comment: ну так ошибку покажи

Comment: Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\php_study\sqltest.php on line 10

Comment: Вот на эту строку ругается: $db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username, $db_password);

Comment: а какая версия php у вас стоит? mysql_connect скорее всего у вас нет.

Comment: Версия php - 5.6.15

Comment: в этой версии нет функции mysql_connect

Comment: а чем можно заменить?

Comment: откатить версию php или перейти на PDO либо mysqlite (просто добавлять букву `i` во всех командах mysql - mysqli_connect, mysqli_select_db и тд).

Comment: Понял, буду пробовать. Большое спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет функции mysql_connect() в вашей версии php.

Решение: откатить версию php на нижнюю или перейти на PDO либо mysqlite (просто добавлять букву `i` во всех командах mysql - mysqli_connect, mysqli_select_db и тд).

Comment: **«просто добавлять букву i во всех командах mysql»** Ну почти так. Многие mysqli-функции ещё с $link первым в списке параметров, а не последним и необязательным, как в mysql. Но в целом переход несложный.